# how to get "a number" in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am using this script to scroll to a comments link:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.comments-link').click(scrollToComments);
    if (location.hash=='#comments') scrollToComments();
    if (location.hash=='#respond') scrollToComments();
});
```

I also want to add:

```
if (location.hash=="#comment-#A-NUMBER#") scrollToComments();
```

The `#A-NUMBER#` part can be any number.

How do I get 'any number' in jquery?

Comment: Why jquery? use basic javascript: `Math.random()`

Comment: #Andy I think he meant "any number" as it appears in the ID of the HTML tag

Comment: @Andy I could be wrong, but I think he's wanting to make the `#A-NUMBER#` part dynamic based on an existing element.  Not a truly random number.

Comment: Yes the link is being produced dynamically - it can be any number in the form <div id="comment-#">blog comment</div>

Comment: Did any of the answers was of help? If not, maybe add more information so we can help you better. Otherwise please tell which answer was the best one for you.

Answer (score 0):

a regular expression like `/\d{1,N}$/` where N is the number of digits you want, concatenated with your id?

Answer (score 0):

You may split the location.hash by '-' and check if the second part is a number.

Answer (score 0):

You could do use the split function to split every #, then you could look for index 2 to get the A-Number.

```
var hashes = String(location.hash).split("#")
var anumber = parseInt(hashes[2])
```

I assume something like this would work.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(/#comment-\d{1,}$/.exec(location.hash)){
scrollToComments();
}
```